# How to convert Mongo DB Object into JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I want to convert a MongoDB object to JSON with PHP. MongoDB gives the key name without string which does not support JSON. I am very familiar with JSON and don't know how to use MongoDB object with PHP. Here is my source code:

```
 <?php
 $str = '[{ DataFound: "DataFound"}]';
 $str1 = json_decode($str,TRUE);
 var_dump($str1);
 ?>
```

It returns null value.

Comment: `[{ DataFound: "DataFound"}]` This is not a valid `JSON`

Comment: I know @sahil, how to make it valid JSON? This is my question.

Comment: Key should be surrounded by quotes. I should be like this
`$str = '[{ "DataFound": "DataFound"}]';`

Answer (score 0):

Now that ive written this i realize it doesnt answer your question exactly but shows you how to debug your json which might be helpful in answering the question

**debugging your json**

```
<?php

$str = '[{DataFound: "DataFound"}]';
$str1 = json_decode($str,TRUE);
$error = json_last_error();
if($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE){
    var_dump($error); // show error if there is one
}
var_dump($str1); // else show your array
?>
```

**PS** valid json string has both key and value wrapped in quotes

```
$str = '[{"DataFound" : "DataFound"}]';
```

**Further Reading**

*And probably more relative to the question asked*

Did a little digging and can see that mongo has a command to dump data into a csv.

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv --fields name,address --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Maybe that is a good option for you and then you can import a csv into your db using [HeideSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/). which i have found to be the best interface for importing csv files.